# socket.io not picking up subfolders

Tags: node.js, socket.io

when I run socket.io locally let say `http://localhost:8000/` this does not pick all the folders for css and js. here's my structure:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>



   <script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

$('.box').click(function(){ 

                var content = $(this).attr('id');
                //console.log(content);     
                socket.emit('click',content);
        });



        socket.on('test', function(content){

            $(".box").css({"background":"grey"});
            $(".one,.two,.three,.four").hide();
            $("#"+content).css({"background":"red"});
            $("."+content).fadeIn();

            //$('.box').css({"background":"grey"});

        }); 
    </script>
```

server.js :

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
      io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
      fs = require('fs');

    // creating the server ( localhost:8000 ) 
    app.listen(8000);

    // on server started we can load our client.html page
    function handler(req, res) {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/client.html', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.writeHead(500);
          return res.end('Error loading client.html');
        }
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
      });

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('click', function(data){
        io.sockets.emit('test',data); 
    });


});
```

console is throwing this below that it cannot be found:

```
"http://localhost:8000/css/normalize.css". 
"http://localhost:8000/css/main.css".
```

Can someone help please?

second question:

I'm very new to this, so not sure if this does not sound stupid. But I would like to run this from actual directory let say: `http://localhost/test/test2:8000` instead of `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: Examine your `handler` function: it only ever sends `client.html`. (The `socket.io.js` file is served by a separate handler attached by socket.io.) You need to base your response on the request URL in [`req.url`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the role of Socket.io. This javascript library handles real-time communication between the clients and your server. In your code, you don't use Socket.io at all: you don't define any connection handler nor do you emit any event.

What you should do instead is modify the code of your HTTP server to serve the files. In your example, you have to edit the `handler` function that handles the incoming requests. Please look at [the documentation for the HTTP module](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html). Your `app` is an [`http.Server` object](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server). Your `handler` function, per the documentation, is:

> The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to [the 'request' event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request).

which handles an [`http.IncomingMessage`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage). You should then look at the [`url` property](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url), which contains the URL that the client requested, in order to serve the correct file. In your example, you always serve the same file: `client.html`.

To conclude, I'd suggest that you should have a look at some javascript libraries that ease the creation of a webserver, for instance [Express](http://expressjs.com), or [Hapi](http://hapijs.com). This will be easier your you than to handle each request by hand.

Comment: I'd suggest (as is @apsillers) you to edit your `handler` function. Read the `req.url` parameter and serve the correct file instead of always sending back `client.html`. To ease this, Express.js has a [static middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) that does exactly what you want.

Comment: I have added the connection and emit fucntions

Comment: Paul Mougel thank you for your answer. But can you help me to rewrite the handler function that it will pick all the folders please?

Comment: If you really want to code this by yourself, read [the source code of the `static` middleware of `connect`](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/static.js) that implements this exact functionnality. Otherwise, I strongly suggest you to use Express...

Comment: is there any simple tutorial out there please?

Comment: I got it working using Express.js thanks so much. Also I;m having another issue if your interested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058012/how-to-control-socket-io-with-on-off-button/20059664?noredirect=1#20059664